# Html nested list styles, stacked list inside an inline list

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html and css. I'm trying to create a `nav` block that contains a nested list.  I want it to look like this:

[image]

But I cannot get the outer list to stack inline.  It ends up looking like this:

[image]

What is wrong with this code?

**HTML:**

```
 <footer>
        <nav id="bottom">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com"><img id ="emailIcon" src="./images/emailIcon.png" width="50" alt="email icon"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Email me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="www.linkedin.com/in"><img id="linkedin" src="./images/linkedInIcon.png" width="50" alt = "linked in icon" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="www.linkedin.com/in">My Linkedin Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="tel:+1number"><img id="phoneIcon" src="./images/phoneIcon.png" width="50" alt="Phone Icon"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="tel:+1number">Call Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
} 

 nav#bottom {
    background-color: rgb(27, 72, 220);
    color: rgb(211, 211, 212);
    padding: 15px;
}

nav#bottom ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    flex: 0 1 150px;
    align-items: center;
}

nav#bottom ul > li {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    align-items: center;
 }

 nav#bottom ul > li > ul > li{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
 }
 
 nav#bottom ul a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding a few things, but mostly that you want `ul /* or whatever container */ { display: flex; }` only as far as flexbox. The default `flex-direction` is `row`, which is what you want; you do not want column, that means vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add another unordered list `ul` inside the list elements `li`, you can use CSS flexbox to style it. I have modified your codes below, a summary of what I did is:

- edited your **HTML** file to remove the unnecessary nesting
- editing your **CSS** for `nav#bottom ul` and `nav#bottom ul > li`
- removed the **CSS** for `nav#bottom ul > li > ul > li`**

**HTML:**

```
 <footer>
        <nav id="bottom">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com"><img id ="emailIcon" src="./images/emailIcon.png" width="50" alt="email icon"/></a>
                    <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Email me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in"><img id="linkedin" src="./images/linkedInIcon.png" width="50" alt = "linked in icon" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in">My Linkedin Page</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="tel:+1number"><img id="phoneIcon" src="./images/phoneIcon.png" width="50" alt="Phone Icon"></a>
                    <a href="tel:+1number">Call Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
      nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      nav#bottom {
        background-color: rgb(27, 72, 220);
        color: rgb(211, 211, 212);
        padding: 15px;
      }

      nav#bottom ul {
        list-style: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        flex: 0 1 150px;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }

      nav#bottom ul > li {
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1.8em;
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }

      nav#bottom ul a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
```

This will achieve what your desired look✨

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you've written gets pretty convoluted pretty quickly, and with that many layers of styles you're not likely to get a desirable result on refactor without revising basically the entire file every time for every little change you have to make.

There's no need for multiple nested `<ul>` elements here, as we can imagine each "group" of links as one single node in the `<nav>`. Because the `<a>` tags are essentially identical, you can even include the `<img>` and the link text as children of the same link.

*For example:*

```
<footer>
  <nav id="bottom">
    <div>
      <ul>
        {/* each li holds one and only one link */}
        <li>
          <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">
            {/* img and text merged into one link */}
            <img id="emailIcon" src="./images/emailIcon.png" width="50" alt="email icon" />
            Email me
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="www.linkedin.com/in">
            <img id="linkedin" src="./images/linkedInIcon.png" width="50" alt="linked in icon" />
            My Linkedin Page
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="tel:+1number">
            <img id="phoneIcon" src="./images/phoneIcon.png" width="50" alt="Phone Icon" />
            Call Me
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

This is lower-level and easier to visualize, which will make it easier to style. Basically all that's left is to treat the `<ul>` as a flexbox so that all of its children (the `<li>` elements) can be displayed inline. The outer `<div>` exists so that you can contain all of the links to as small an area as you'd like.

```
nav#bottom {
  background-color: rgb(27, 72, 220);
  color: rgb(211, 211, 212);
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  div {
    text-align: center;
    // width will determine how close each link is to one another
    width: 50%;
  }

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    // you can play with space-around and space-between for different effects
    justify-content: space-between;

    a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    img {
      // break image and text to different lines
      display: block;
      // center within li
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
}
```

With the above, I get a result almost identical to the goal you set, granted with image alts instead of the original files. Less is definitely more when it comes to HTML/CSS. Generally, the simpler the solution, the cleaner the result. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested ul and li you can use (flex-direction: row) for larger devices and (flex-direction: column) for mobile devices.

For Example:

Larger Device:

```
nav#bottom ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    flex: 0 1 150px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; //This behaviour is by default
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Mobile Device:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nav li{
Display :inline;
Padding:15px
Vertical -align: middle

Nav a{
Text-decoration:none
Padding:8px 8px
Vertical -align: middle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of nested `<li>` ,so I put both the image and text inside a single `<li>` .In stylesheet, I changed `display` property to `flex` and its diretion to `column` and added `display flex` to `<ul>` .

HTML :-

```
    <footer>
<nav id="bottom">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com"><img id="emailIcon" src="./images/emailIcon.png" width="50" alt="email icon" /></a>
            <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Email me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="www.linkedin.com/in"><img id="linkedin" src="./images/linkedInIcon.png" width="50" alt="linked in icon" /></a>
            <a href="www.linkedin.com/in">My Linkedin Page</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="tel:+1number"><img id="phoneIcon" src="./images/phoneIcon.png" width="50" alt="Phone Icon"></a>
            <a href="tel:+1number">Call Me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS :-

```
    nav a {
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav#bottom {
       background-color: rgb(27, 72, 220);
       color: rgb(211, 211, 212);
       padding: 15px;
    }

    nav ul{
       display: flex;
       gap: 50px;
    }

    nav#bottom ul {
       list-style: none;
       list-style-type: none;
       list-style-image: none;
       flex: 0 1 150px;
       align-items: center;
    }

    nav#bottom ul>li {
       font-size: 1em;
       line-height: 1.8em;
       list-style-type: none;
       list-style: none;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       align-items: center;
    }

    nav#bottom ul>li>ul>li {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       align-items: center;
       text-align: center;
    }

    nav#bottom ul a {
       color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Try the above code and you will get your desired outcome!